# Make publication all values default to check in subscription center

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe, subscription-center

[image: All the highlighted checkbox in the screenshot I want to be checked for all subscriber]

I searched and didn't found any way to do that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Subscriber needs to be present on your publication lists with Active status to have all boxes checked here - so try adding subscribers to your lists. Remember that this might be illegal to add subscribers to your lists without consent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just need to know is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No, there isn’t